# Not able to send mail from heroku using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, nodemailer

This is the error I get on heroku when I am trying to send emails from my deployed application.

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586059+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._onError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:579:20)
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:261:18)
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586067+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
2018-07-28T21:37:39.586069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

I am using nodemailer version 4.6.7 and here's the code:

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports = {
   sendMail: function(email) {
      console.log(email)
      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sails.config.connections.mailer);

      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Medico " <test@testgmail.com>', // sender address
        to: email, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Test', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: 'Hello world?' // html body
      };

      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      });
   }
}
```

I am using the generated app password from google and that works perfectly fine when I run it locally but on heroku it is throwing error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set up your clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken, and accessToken in the sailsConfig? Also, how are you deploying to Heroku? From Github? If so, did you exclude that config in your gitignore and replace it with env variables on Heroku?

Comment: yes I have done all that.

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban I am having the same issue... Did you find a solution to this?